# How to delete a single cached username from Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Somewhere along the line I accidentally typed my password into the username field on a website in Chrome. Now every time I go back to that site my password is shown as an option to fill as my username. I didn't specifically save the username/password combo, it is just the little drop down that appears when you start to type.

Is it possible to clear this single item? I would rather not have to clear all form data.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Go to `Options` → `Personal Stuff` → `Manage Saved Passwords`, hover over what you want to delete, and then click the `x`.

**UPDATE** (credits to camster342): It's now in `Settings` -> `Show Advanced Settings...` and `Manage Passwords` is the second link under the `Passwords and Forms` section.

If the data you want to delete is not a password but rather a saved form follow this:

> When you type in a form field, a menu may appear, containing past text that you've typed in the field. To delete a specific piece of saved text, select it in the menu using the arrows on your keyboard, then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>.

<sub>*[(source)](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142893&from=142464&rd=1)*</sub>

On Mac OS it's <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>.

Comment: NP :) (and now for padding :))

Comment: Just to let you know, I realise this is a pretty old answer, but the location of that option has changed... It's now in Settings -> Show Advanced Settings... and Managed Saved Passwords is the second link under the Passwords and Forms section.

Comment: Lastly to keep the form from autofilling with the wrong information when refreshed, I had to delete the site cookie. To do this, click on the icon just to the left of the URL in Chrome, then click "Show Cookie and Site Data". Select the proper domain, and click "Remove" and then "Close".

Comment: It appears this answer is now out of date again... I cannot find where to delete just a username that autofills by using the menu. Fortunately the `shift + delete` option works for me.

Comment: Thanks @Wahki02 your suggestion worked for me in Brave browser. Prob would in any chromium flavor :)

Answer (score 56):

It is possible to delete the single or all the username from the Google user-box. Simply select the require username by keyboard arrows. Then use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>.

Answer (score 12):

1. Open a web page in which a data field showing the problematic value appears
2. Double-click the field to make it show its drop down
3. Highlight the problematic value with your mouse
4. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>

The value disappears and won't bother you again.

Comment: In Firefox, <kbd>Delete</kbd> alone would suffice.

Comment: This is not working any more.

Answer (score 7):

On Mac you highlight what you want to delete and then click "shift" "fn" and "command" all at once and then click the delete and it will be deleted from the username section

Comment: Ugh - thank you!  I've tried about 50 different things and this is the first one that worked

Answer (score 2):

I had trouble finding the site using `Settings -> Show Advanced Settings -> Managed Saved Passwords`, but was able to find the site using https://passwords.google.com. Then you just click the `X` to delete your username/password for the site.

Answer (score 1):

I had to try this myself recently on Mac. What worked for me is `fn` + `shift` + `delet`

Answer (score 0):

I actually discovered the solution myself, I'm on Google Chrome and I think it may work on Firefox and Internet Explorer too.

When typing your mail, highlight the suggestion but don't click it, then press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Supr</kbd> at the same time.

Comment: Can you explain what the "Supr" key is? If you mean the Super key, isn't that usually just a modifier?

Answer (score -1):

I am using Chrome Version 54.0.2840.98. What worked for me was looking to the top right in the address bar. A key pops up. You can click the key and it will show you the list of available logins for the username you are filling in.

[image: screenshot of Address Bar and Key]

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, some of those don't work at all. I tried the highlight shift delete several times. Doesn't work at all. 
I don't want to delete all my passwords. So those aren't helpful. 
The only one that works is fn shift delete. Thanks.

Comment: After reviewing some of the other answers it seems like they are appropriate.  Your response seems more appropriate as a comment than an answer.  I suggest you rephrase your response under the answer that doesn't work and be more precise about what does and does not work.