# Delete username chrome autofill login using in Portuguese macbook

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I accidentally tried logging in on my banking website writing my password in the username field. I have click "don't save password". However it saved the username autofill.

I tried deleting it through "Manage Passwords" or "Autofill settings" but there is nothing there (which was expected). I also saw a solution [here](https://superuser.com/questions/303387/how-to-delete-a-single-cached-username-from-chrome) but is not working.

I use a macbook (yosemite) with **no delete** key and with Portuguese keyboard.
How do I delete the username autofill now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove one or all auto-complete text entries in Chrome?](http://superuser.com/questions/175250/how-to-remove-one-or-all-auto-complete-text-entries-in-chrome)

Answer (score 2):

I quote an answer from [How to remove one or all auto-complete text entries in Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/175250/how-to-remove-one-or-all-auto-complete-text-entries-in-chrome)

> #### Linux and Windows
>
> Just highlight it in the dropdown list (using the arrow keys, or your
>   mouse cursor) and press <kbd>delete</kbd> on your keyboard.
>
> Note that you may have to press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> in
>   some cases, like if the autocomplete is in the address bar (URL)
>   field.
>
> #### Mac
>
> 1. Start typing so that the unwanted autocomplete URL comes up.
> 2. Hit <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> if you have a compact keyboard or <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>delete ⌦</kbd> if you have a
>      keyboard with separate <kbd>delete ⌦</kbd> key (and no <kbd>fn</kbd>).
>      If you have a non-Apple keyboard, <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>
>      should do the trick.

In your case you do not have a delete button on your keyboard.

> Macbook pros do not have a delete key. They have a backspace key, but
>   in the US version only, the word "delete" is written on it. It still
>   works as a backspace key, and you still have to use the fn key to get
>   it to work as a delete key.

Comment: As I explained in my question, I don't have a delete key.

Comment: @Miguel use onscreen keyboard? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wt0QhT7oM3s It should give you the default US keyboard. Otherwise just change the keyboard in the settings.

Comment: Ok, I just realised that my backspace is the delete key... There is [this](http://superuser.com/questions/175250/how-to-remove-one-or-all-auto-complete-text-entries-in-chrome#comment634461_175261)  comment from the answer you linked. I have managed to deleted. Thanks!

Comment: @Miguel thanks for noticing me. I have adjusted my answer accordingly.

Comment: You should just VTC this question as a duplicate of the other one ...

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm not sure on how to do that also I'm not sure If I can do that with my current reputation of 314 points. I did comment that it was a duplication. but after he told me its about the delete key I wasn't sure anymore.

Comment: Never mind. I've done it. You can always flag as duplicate in future.